# Caching Tastypie requests

Tags: tastypie

I am using Django with Tastypie to provide a restful api. Since each GET request will produce a query to the backend database, what is the best way to cache the request using redis cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider [Johnny-Cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/) it will cache all ORM queries to memcached. It does work with TastyPie, I have used it for this same reason.

Here is a good discussion of ORM caching [convore](https://convore.com/django-community/django-orm-caching/).

Comment: Now that Convore is gone, anyone have a new link to that article?